# Any application that can split scanned PDF's on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications, pdf

Are there any iPad PDF apps that either automatically or manually can split scanned PDF's into multiple pages?

At school, I receive many scanned PDFs that have 2 physical pages per PDF page, which makes them more cumbersome to work with since it requires me to manually pan around to see the next page.

Comment: That task is not trivial even when using a computer. A possible work-flow would be duplicating each page and then cropping only the respective half. On a computer this can be done manually or even using a script with [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and [pdfcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/). But I doubt that an iPad app exists that will do the job. I would also recommend trying [GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html).

Answer (score 2):

### [PDFPen for iPad](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/iOS/index.html)

has recently been released. It will permit you to split PDFs by saving a new copy of the PDF and then deleting pages you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I've not come across anything that will alter PDF's like that, however Goodreader (and Goodreader for iPad) is in my opinion the best PDF reader app

It has quite a few reading modes and easier pan and zoom controls (multitouch gestures) that may provide a better reading experience than using the iPad's built in viewer.

The downside is it is a commercial program, but at $5, it is money well spent.

[GoodReader for iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id363448914?mt=8)